# Concatenate variable to array map method

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm passing a variable to the component as below and mapping that to filter the array

Example:

```
<TestSection name={Stackoverflow} />
```

In Testsection component

```
  const TestSection = ({ name }) => {
  const Data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        Json {
          TEST {
            Stackoverflow {
              title
              description
            }
            Overflowstack {
              title
              description
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );

  console.log(name) // this outputs Stackoverflow and this should be the input for map function
    return (
       {Data.Json.TEST.name.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={`test-${index}`}>
          <ul>
            <li>{item.title}</li>
            <li>{item.description}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       ))}
      );
    };
```

Passing name to the map array doesn't work. The intention is to return the array data based on the calling component name. How to pass the name to the map array ? Thanks

Comment: You do not need to pass anything inside map array.
`name` would be accessible inside it, since it is a prop passed to `TestSection`

Comment: simply `Data.Json.TEST` doesn't contain `name`... `Data.Json.TEST[name].map(` - for `name` = stack... or over.. (one of defined TEST child/properties) ?